# Are there fixed conditions for how long a log stream is open?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm writing a concurrent tailing utility for watching multiple AWS CloudWatch log groups across many regions simultaneously, and in CloudWatch logs, there are log *groups*, which contain many log *streams* that are rotated occasionally. Thus, to tail a log group, one must find the latest log stream, read it in a loop, and occasionally check for a new log stream, and start reading that in a loop.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this, but is there a set of published conditions upon which I can conclude that a log stream has been "closed?" I'm assuming I'll need to have multiple tasks tailing multiple log streams in a group up until a certain cut-off point, but I don't know how to logically determine that a log stream has been completed and to abandon tailing it.

Does anyone know whether such published conditions exist?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find that published anywhere.

If AWS had some mechanism to know that a log stream was "closed" or would no longer receive log entries, I believe their own console for a stream would make use of it somehow.  As it stands, when you view even a very old stream in the console, it will show this message at the bottom:

[image]

I know it is not a direct answer to your question, but I believe that is strong indirect evidence that AWS can't tell when a log stream is "closed" either.  Resuming auto retry on an old log stream generates traffic that would be needless, so if they had a way to know the stream was "closed" they would disable that option for such streams.

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html) says

> A log stream is a sequence of log events that share the same source.

Since each new "source" will create a new log stream, and since CloudWatch supports *many* different services and options, there won't be a single answer.  It depends on too many factors.  For example, with the Lambda service, each lambda container will be a new source, and AWS Lambda may create new containers based on many factors like lambda execution volume, physical work in its data center, outages, changes to lambda code, etc.  And that is just for *one* potential stream source for log streams.

You've probably explored options, but these may give some insights into ways to achieve what you're looking to do:

- The CLI has an option to `tail` that will include *all* log streams in a group: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/tail.html though if you're building your own utility the CLI won't likely be an option
- Some options are discussed at [how to view aws log real time (like tail -f)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018931/how-to-view-aws-log-real-time-like-tail-f) but there are no mentions of published conditions for when a stream is "closed"
- [When does AWS CloudWatch create new log streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659141/when-does-aws-cloudwatch-create-new-log-streams) may yield some insights